# In how many ways can $5$ teaching posts be filled if $2$ posts are reserved for American candidates?

Tags: combinatorics

For the post of $5$ teachers, there are $23$ applicants, $2$ posts are reserved for American candidates and there are $7$ American candidates among the applicants. In how many ways can the selection be made ?

Answer in textbook is given as

selection of $2$ American candidates out of $7$ + selection of $3$ from $16$ others left

$$\binom{7}{2} \times \binom{16}{3} $$

But, I am using combinations of $2$ Americans and $3$ others from left $16$ + combinations of $3$ Americans and $2$ others from left $16$ + combinations of $4$ Americans and $1$ other from left $16$ + combinations of $5$ Americans 
$$\binom{7}{2} \times\binom{16}{3} +\binom{7}{3} \times\binom{16}{2} +\binom{7}{4} \times\binom{16}{1}+\binom{7}{5} \times\binom{16}{0}$$

Is it wrong? Why? Please explain.

Comment: It appears to me that the book's answer is wrong, since they did not say the other positions had to be filled by persons other than Americans.

Comment: Enumeration problems should be tagged with combinatorics.  You could also add the combinations tag here since you are selecting subsets.  The permutations tag should be reserved for counting the number of arrangements of a set of objects.

Comment: The book answer interprets the question as saying there must be exactly two Americans, whereas you have interpreted the question as saying there must be at least two Americans.  In my opinion, either interpretation is plausible.  It's a poorly stated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem is here is interpretation of question by me.
The book answer interprets the question as saying there must be exactly two Americans, whereas I have interpreted the question as saying there must be at least two Americans. It's a poorly stated question

Answer (score 1):

this is because the no of ways you can select 2 American candidates out of 7 is 7C2-------M

and the number of ways you can select the rest is (23-7)C(5-2)-------------N

Thus, total ways = M*N
= 7C2 * 16C3

Comment: Your answer is incorrect since it is possible to select more than two Americans to fill the posts.

Comment: But it's the same as in the book